# Close dialog and execute automation script on same button (IBM Maximo)

Tags: dialog, jython, maximo

Is there any workaround to execute an automation script over dialog in Maximo and next close it with `dialogok` event using the same push button?

Comment: fixed sentences and typos for smoother sentence flow

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the answer you want to hear, but as of Maximo 7.6.0.8 (the latest version currently available), the only "workaround" would be a custom Java Bean class.

Answer (score 0):

It's is possible to trigger two actions with one button. I've not tested it with automationscripts though....

For example use this in de button xml:

```
mxevent="dialogok" value="ROUTEWF"
```

You can add a sigoption with the same name as the action and make sure that you expand the 'Advanced Signature Options' section and set 'This is an action that must be invoked by user in the UI'.

Answer (score 0):

You could create and object launch point automation script therefore when you click OK in the menu the object will be saved and the automation script triggered.
If you already know that some field is going to be update, you could do it with an attribute launch point for that object.